# In Visual Studio, how do I include a built file in another project?

Tags: visual-studio

How specifically should my command line be written as to copy the output from one project into the output of another project?  The list of macros that are avaliable does not list anyway of accessing OTHER project directories under the same solution:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4(v=vs.80).aspx
```

Here is what I currently have:

```
copy "$(TargetDir)FILE_TO_MOVE.EXE" ""
```

What should I put in the second quote to complete this command?

NOTE:  A similar question does NOT actually show you HOW to do it, which is what I am asking:  [Visual Studio 2008: How do I include project output as an embedded resource in another project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337764/visual-studio-2008-how-do-i-include-project-output-as-an-embedded-resource-in-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much easier to do it the other way around, have the project that has the dependency on the file also copy the file.  Which you can do in the IDE without pre/post buid event or macro trickery.

Ensure the source project is built.  Right click the target project, Add Existing Item and select the file.  Click the added file in the Solution Explorer window and set the properties to Build Action = Content, Copy to Output Directory = Copy if newer.  And right-click the target project, Project Dependencies, tick the source project to ensure that it always gets built first.

Comment: Wait, it doesn't update the file though.  When I "Add Exiting Item", it just copy the file into the target Project from the source Project.  How do I make sure it actually update from the source Project every time the solution is built?

Comment: Click the arrow on the Add button in the dialog and select "Add As Link".

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that yout are copying the "FILE_TO_MOVE.EXE" in the post build events of your project.

The thing about the build events in Visual Studio is that they are run just like a batch file, therefore I beileve that the easiest way to solve your problem is to use a system environment variable in your project... This way your code would be similar to the one below.

```
copy "$(TargetDir)FILE_TO_MOVE.EXE" "$(MyVariable)"
```

Note: Visual Studio doesn't let you use your environment variable like this: %MyVariable%.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way now would be to simply add your secondary project, i.e a Windows Service, to the *References* of the main project.

For example if you have a main GUI project (that the solution was created with), and a second Service project added to the solution, adding it to *References* of the GUI project will cause the EXE and the PDB of the service to be placed in the Debug/Release folder of you main project.

I am not sure if you still need to add the *Project Dependancy* as Hans suggested . This is probably automatic thanks to the reference.